# Search using apache solr

Tags: json, solr

I have currently indexed Oracle table in Apache Solr 6.6.  I need to display the matched value as part of the response globally without repeating.
If I Search rty333 for example. The JSON response matching keyword and then indexed result. . Please find the example below

```
          //Here results are found matching id and name

         "response":"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":2.3025851
          "docs":[
           {
                 "id":"rty333",
                "emp_name":["uuuu"],
                "company":["Corsair Microsystems Inc."],
                 "price":[74.99],
                 "popularity":[7]
             },
             {
                 "id":"1111",
                "emp_name":["rty333"],
                "company":["elec Inc"],
                 "price":[74.99],
                 "popularity":[7]
             } 
           }
```

How can I configure Matched: {id, name} and map the global fields with the indexed fields.
emp_name=> name
id=> id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html - Highlighting will tell you which fields and which terms matched your query for each document.

Comment: But I want to display it on the response separately  that I have mentioned as part of "Matched" in the example

Comment: You're going to have to add that information yourself, Solr will not be able to provide it for you.

Comment: Yes true. But how to map response headers with the query strings. I know the response headers and query fields. Where and how to map is my question

Comment: You do that in your controller; you take the information from the highlighted section in the response and determine which fields have highlighting attached, and then add that part to the response before returning it. You can also create a custom component for Solr that adds it to the response; I'd suggest starting by looking at how the highlighting component does it, or possibly looking at the debug information returned by the searchers - and if that data is available to be added to the response.

Comment: ok. Can't that be done as part of Solr itself. For example something under this                                  {
    "responseHeader": {
        "..."
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 1,
        "start": 0,    }}. Since these are fixed and gets displayed only once per matched result

Comment: Sure, but Solr doesn't support what you're asking for out of the box, so you'll either have to add it yourself by proxying the request through a controller / service, or add a custom component to Solr to add the information you're looking for. I'm guessing it'll have to be added as a separate section to the response, but that should be the same when it comes to functionality.

Comment: Oh ok. Then I will try doing it using highlight feature. As I guess I can get the matching fields {id : "4555"} returned as response from Solr into Java controller and then add these extra header to the response that my class builds. Tell me one thing what if I search for a phrase like 1234 789. There is a white space. In that case I get a lot of results matching either 1234/ 789/ 1234 789. In this case how will highlight feature help me. If I need to match Id which is actually 1234 789. I see 1234/ 789 is also getting highlighted. How to handle in this situation?

Comment: If you want to only have exact matches for that field, define it as a `string` field - that will only give exact matches, while a `text` field will split on the space by default.

Comment: Since I need both the results. I need to fetch only the string value that gives the exact match and text would remain as. Is that possible.

Comment: Use two fields, one with the `string` field type and one with the original one (probably `text` or similar). Use a `copyField` instruction to make sure the same content get into both fields. Use the field you need depending on your use case.

Comment: Yeah. I will try it.